# Powershell bitlocker, cant find path in regedit

Tags: powershell, regedit, bitlocker

When I want to check in my registry for changing keys for bitlocker I don't seem to have this location:

`HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\FVE`

The FVE map isn't there. So I also can't change these keys with PowerShell.
Its a local computer, not in a domain.

Anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: Possibly better posting this on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) as it doesn't seem to be a programming question.

Comment: As dumb as it seems, you can just add the keys manually...or just turn on BitLocker on the machine...and pause or cancel the encryption if you don't *really* want it on.

Comment: You can also edit group policy and apply it...which will set the missing keys as well (you don't need MBAM to do this).

Answer (score 0):

You need to Edit local group policy. Located here:

```
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\BitLocker Drive Encryption\Choose drive encryption method and cipher strength
```

You will also need to install the MBAM Client in order for that reg hive to appear.
Once you enable the GPO and install the MBAM Client you will be able to change what you want within the registry. However, local group policy works just fine in this case.